# Input hidden with array value - Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm trying to send an array for use in javascript from html with a Ruby's variable like this:

```
 <% @data.each do |d| %>
   <input type="hidden" id="name" value= "<%= d.name %>">
 <% end %>
```

"data" is a variable of a model

```
def index
    @data = organizations.all
end
```

in js i used a variable with id "name"

```
var nombre = document.getElementById("name").value;
var x = name;
```

I want that x is an array like:

```
["Org1","Org2","Org3"]
```

thanks for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating X amount of fields with the same id. That's a problem, the ID should be unique. There is an alternative though, you can use A CLASS!

```
 <% @data.each do |d| %>
   <input type="hidden" class="js-names" value= "<%= d.name %>">
 <% end %>
```

Get the list of elements

```
// Array of elements
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('js-names'));
var names = elements.map(function(element) { return element.value; });
```

However, a better approach is definitely using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)